# read a class from a file change it and put it back in the file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

```
transactionsFile.seekp(0,transactionsFile.beg);
transactionsFile.seekg(0,transactionsFile.beg);
while (!transactionsFile.eof()){
    transactionsFile.read((char*) &tempTrans, sizeof(Transaction));
    tempTrans.amount = 50;
    transactionsFile.write((char*) &tempTrans, sizeof(Transaction));
}
transactionsFile.seekg(0,transactionsFile.beg);
while (!transactionsFile.eof()){
    transactionsFile.read((char*) &tempTrans, sizeof(Transaction));
    cout << tempTrans.transID <<" " << tempTrans.amount <<" "<< tempTrans.creditAcctID <<" "<< tempTrans.debitAcctID <<endl;
}
```

it doest change anything in the file.
and in the printing its print nothing cause it dont insert the second while at all
(when i do only the printing it works fine)

Answer (score 0):

When you `read` from a file it advances the file pointer to the next location.
To write to the same record you read, you will need to back up to where the read started and write.

```
std::streampos    read_posn = transactionsFile.tellg();
while (transactionsFile.read((char*) &tempTrans, sizeof(Transaction)))
{
    std::streampos next_read_posn = transactionsFile.tellg();
    tempTrans.amount = 50;
    transactionsFile.seekp(read_posn);
    transactionsFile.write((char *) &tempTrans, sizeof(Transaction));
    transactionsFile.seekg(next_read_posn);
    read_posn = next_read_posn;
}
```

**Edit 1:**  Saved the read position after the read.  Restored the read position after the write.

Comment: it help a lot. but there is weird problem. it get the first and second classes change them and put them back.

Comment: but from the second the read is on the ame class. and the write is contiuning. endless loop....

Comment: I've edited my answer.  I save the read position before writing, then restored it after writing.